# Unique identifier for documents stored in Jackrabbit

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, dms, jcr-sql2

I m fairly new to Apache Jackrabbit and I could not get a concrete answer to this question as far as I checked. Hence I m posting the following question:

I need a unique identifier for the documents stored in Jackrabbit (irrespective of whether the documents are stored in File System or DB). I did found a method **`getIdentifier()`** in **`javax.jcr.Node`**. But not sure whether it unique for each document node inside the repository and whether can I rely on this identfier to fetch the document for updation or deletion?

Basically I m looking for a unique identifier like the one returned from **`new IDfSysObject().getObjectId().getId()`** in case of **`Documentum`** through which I can back track the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier is indeed unique, but it might not be stable (for instance, when the document is moved around).

You can make it stable though by adding the mixin type "mix:referenceable" (see https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.8%20Referenceable%20Nodes)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you exactly mean by document is moving around? You mean moved to a different folder or workspace?

Comment: Yes, moved to a different location in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So as you said with "mix:referenceable" i m good to go with node.getidentifier to uniquely refer a  document right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is for.

Comment: Thanks again. Cheers